# How can I optimize the algorithm to find the longest common subsequence (LCS) between two strings?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, lcs

An algorithm used to efficiently find the LCS between two strings:

1. Define two strings, string1 and string2, with lengths m and n, respectively.
2. Create a 2D array, dp, with dimensions (m+1) x (n+1). Initialize all the elements of dp to 0.
3. Iterate over the characters of string1 from left to right (i) and string2 from top to bottom (j).
4. If string1[i] is equal to string2[j], increment dp[i+1][j+1] by 1. This means the current characters match, and the length of the LCS ending at this point is one more than the LCS ending at the previous characters.
5. If string1[i] is not equal to string2[j], take the maximum value between dp[i][j+1] and dp[i+1][j] and store it in dp[i+1][j+1]. This means the current characters do not match, so the length of the LCS ending at this point is the maximum of the LCS ending at the previous characters in either string1 or string2.
6. After iterating over all characters, the value of dp[m][n] will be the length of the LCS between string1 and string2.
7. To retrieve the actual LCS, start from dp[m][n] and backtrack through the dp array. If string1[i-1] is equal to string2[j-1], add the character to the LCS and move diagonally to dp[i-1][j-1]. Otherwise, move to the left if dp[i][j-1] is greater than dp[i-1][j], or move upward if dp[i-1][j] is greater.
8. Repeat step 7 until reaching the top-left corner of the dp array.

By following this algorithm, the longest common subsequence between two strings can be found in programming.

An example of Java code:

```
public static String repeatCharacter(char ch, int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
char ch = 'X';

System.out.println("Enter size of first string");
int m = myObj.next();
String string1 = repeatCharacter(ch, m);
System.out.println("Enter size of first string");
int m = myObj.next()
String string2 = repeatCharacter(ch, n);
String lcs = "";

System.out.println("Enter first string");
string1 = myObj.nextLine(); 
System.out.println("Enter second string");
string1 = myObj.nextLine(); 
int dp[m+1][n+1];
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < m + 1; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
          dp[i][j] = 0;
     }
}

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          if (string1[i] = string2[j])
              dp[i+1][j+1]++;
          else
              dp[i+1][j+1] = Math.max(dp[i][j+1], dp[i+1][j]);
     }
}

i = m, j = n;
while (i > -1 && j > -1) {
    if (string1[i-1] = string2[j-1]) {
        lcs = lcs + string1[i-1];
        i--;
        j--;
    }
    else if (dp[i][j-1] > dp[i-1][j])
        i--;
    else
        j--;
}
```

However, using nested for loops can take O(m n) in both time and space.

How can I optimize the time complexity and the space complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: *"How can I optimize this algorithm?"* What do you mean? You said it was "efficient". Are you looking for another, even better algorithm?

Comment: @Olivier I am looking for another, even better algorithm.

Comment: Asking for "a better algorithm" and putting in the statement sounds like an academic task and without effort (code on your part), the chances of receiving a response are low. On the other hand, what are your criteria? better in what sense? As the question stands, don't be surprised if they give it a negative and/or close it (in all 3 places you have a negative). To avoid that, carry out the implementation in some programming language, put the cases, the metrics you have, the errors there are, the inputs and outputs you expect, having that, it is likely that someone will give you a hand.

Comment: What about this https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~rezaul/papers/DP-SODA-06.pdf ? Don't have enough time to implement, but there has been some work. Found this one after checking wiki and following names until I dug out the article...

Comment: How big are the strings that you intend to match against each other? 1000 or 10^6 characters? The solution for each of those will look very different.  If m*n gets too big then the algorithm using a 2D array of counts will be very much slower.

Comment: Did you bother to read *at least* the paragraph on optimization in the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Code_optimization)? No? Because you would have to implement it yourself? Sorry, but what have YOU tried to achieve any gain, so the community can discuss your approach and help you?

Comment: And why the heck are you criticizing in a comment your OWN question?

Comment: Ok, fine. So you not only translated your *question* for the Spanish and Portuguese Stackoverflows, but also your *self-critcizing comment* one-to-one into Portuguese. And strangely enough, this critique-comment was originally written in the Spanish SO by [fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx). Sorry to ask, but you aren't a bot, aren't you?

Comment: It seems to be a thing that DNA people do since the earlier related question for [faster LCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808341/how-can-i-optimize-the-algorithm-to-find-the-longest-common-subsequence-lcs-be) seems fairly well answered. But how does it help ? It seems to me that it will add random noise guff to start and end of any precise matches and always yield a chunk of near random letters for any possible pair of inputs with (ACGT in roughly equal proportions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case  the linear search approach is more suitable and efficient :

```
public class LCS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first string:");
        String string1 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter second string:");
        String string2 = scanner.nextLine();

        int[][] dp = calculateLCS(string1, string2);

        String lcs = findLCS(dp, string1, string2);

        System.out.println("Length of Longest Common Subsequence: " + dp[string1.length()][string2.length()]);
        System.out.println("Longest Common Subsequence: " + lcs);
    }

    private static int[][] calculateLCS(String string1, String string2) {
        int m = string1.length();
        int n = string2.length();

        int[][] dp = new int[m + 1][n + 1];

        IntStream.range(0, m + 1).forEach(i -> dp[i][0] = 0);
        IntStream.range(0, n + 1).forEach(j -> dp[0][j] = 0);

        IntStream.range(0, m).forEach(i ->
                IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(j -> {
                    if (string1.charAt(i) == string2.charAt(j)) {
                        dp[i + 1][j + 1] = dp[i][j] + 1;
                    } else {
                        dp[i + 1][j + 1] = Math.max(dp[i][j + 1], dp[i + 1][j]);
                    }
                })
        );

        return dp;
    }

    private static String findLCS(int[][] dp, String string1, String string2) {
        StringBuilder lcs = new StringBuilder();
        int i = string1.length(), j = string2.length();
        while (i > 0 && j > 0) {
            if (string1.charAt(i - 1) == string2.charAt(j - 1)) {
                lcs.insert(0, string1.charAt(i - 1));
                i--;
                j--;
            } else if (dp[i - 1][j] > dp[i][j - 1]) {
                i--;
            } else {
                j--;
            }
        }
        return lcs.toString();
    }
}
```